# Using Elasticsearch to return the N most recent tags?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm storing blog posts in ElasticSearch. Each blog post has an array of tags, and each post can have 0 or more tags. I know how to use a terms facet to return the N most popular tags. What I'd like is a search that returns the N most recent tags instead. I suppose I could just query the posts individually, date sorted most recent and build the result set of recent tags by hand (removing duplicate tags), but I'm hoping there's a query I can use to do that within ES instead. Is this possible?

Comment: It is not clear to me on which date you want to sort, do you mean the date of the post or do you track dates with the tags?

Comment: Each post has a Date field, in seconds since the epoch.

Comment: if `Article A` is posted with tags `[foo, bar, baz]` and then `Article B` is posted with `[apple, orange, lemon]`, what is your expected order of tags?

Comment: I'd expect the tags from the most recent post to appear first, so : [apple, orange, lemon, foo, bar, baz].

Answer (score 0):

you could save tags as child documents and append create date, then sort by create date field